# Cannot use pyttsx3 Python module

Tags: python

I was trying to do a basic voice script in Python, but it gives me an error and I think it is because of `pyttsx3`. Can someone help me?

Code:

```
def speak(text):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 153, in <module>
    speak("Repita")
  File "main.py", line 23, in speak
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/espeak.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import _espeak, toUtf8, fromUtf8
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/_espeak.py", line 18, in <module>
    dll = cdll.LoadLibrary('libespeak.so.1')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 451, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libespeak.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you don't have `espeak` installed on your system. That's why it is giving error

```
libespeak.so.1 error: no such file or directory found.
```

Try to install espeak using:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install espeak
```